# count t vs actual number in kdb select statement

Tags: kdb

I noticed the following

```
select (count t)#`test from t
```

Returns

```
flip (enlist `x)!enlist enlist `test`test`test
```

Vs

```
select 3#`test from t
```

Which returns

```
flip (enlist `x)!enlist `test`test`test
```

Similar with `select (sum 1 2)#1 from t` vs `select(1 + 2)#1 from t` etc

Anyone know the reason why key words in the select seems to cause the return to be a table with one row nested list containing x element vs a table with x rows?

Answer (score 5):

It's because kdb recognises `count` and `sum` as aggregations and has special treatment for them (it enlists the result).

For example if you were to slightly change the `count` and `sum` to lambdas (which kdb won't recognise) you get the other results you expect:

```
q)select ({count x}t)#`test from t
x
----
test
test
test

q)select ({sum x}1 2)#1 from t
x
-
1
1
1
```

The reason kdb "recognises" certain common aggregations and auto-enlists them is because otherwise simple selects such as `select sum a from tab` would give a rank error as the sum returns an atom but a table column must be a list, e.g.

```
q)select {sum x}a from t
'rank
  [0]  select {sum x}a from t
       ^

/versus

q)select sum a from t
a
-
6
```

There's also a deeper reason which is to do with map/reduce aggregations over database partitions but that's beyond scope for this problem. The list of recognised aggregations is stored in the variable `.Q.a0`. See also https://code.kx.com/q/basics/qsql/#special-functions